# What does "Honor your non-compete" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In drama movie *Bombshell (2019)*, FOX CEO Roger meets with Murdoch family after Megyn filed
sexual harrashment lawsuit on him:

> Rupert Murdoch: Roger, you built an amazing business. No one can take
> that away from you. But under the circumstances, this is a lot of
> money. And it won't look good to the people that don't know your
> worth. Take it. **Honor your non-compete**.

What does "Honor your non-compete" mean?

Comment: You may want to read this first: [Non-compete clause.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often a contract of employment includes a section where the employee agrees that if they stop working for the employer, they will not, for some stated period, work for another employer doing the same kind of business (a competitor). This is often called a 'non-compete' or 'non-competition' clause'.

[Non-competition (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/non-competition)